How to use flutter in dart?
I need to create a mobile application using flutter framework and dart language. I am using asp.net for this project. But i dont know how to use that. and flutter is not started.
I hope i will get the connection idea between dart and the flutter

what is the requirement that needs asp.net?

First Android Studio with install flutter plugin also add Flutter SDK with your Environment variable. After Restart your Device, Check cmd with dart sdk version and also execute

flutter doctor

to set all properties or not.Then Android studio terminal with execute
flutter create my_project_name


Flutter uses dart by default. If you are using asp.net for backend and you want to use Flutter for your frontend then you need to create a new Flutter app using the command below.
flutter create your_app_name

Before this make sure to install flutter. Visit Flutter Getting Started to understand how Flutter works.
